# Ice cream flavors

Tags: combinatorics

A survey was taken among $600$ middle school students for their preferred ice cream flavours.

- $250$ like strawberry
- $100$ liked both strawberry and vanilla
- $130$ like strawberry but not chocolate
- $120$ like only vanilla
- $300$ like only one flavor
- $270$ students said they liked vanilla
- $30$ students like all three flavors

Questions:

- How many do not like any of the $3$ flavors?
- How many like at least one of the $3$ flavors?
- How many like at least $2$ flavors?
- How many like chocolate?

Comment: If you are having problems in solving such exercises it might be best for you to start by drawing Venn diagram's (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)

Comment: I feel like we are missing some data, unless I misunderstood what we have.

Comment: The last constraint you added says the same as another one before it. Regardless, I believe it is enough information to get an answer: I am making a post now.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a trick I missed, your problem seems impossible for me, as I can find a lot of possible answers.

There are 8 possibilities for each student, and we have only 6 constraints, which isn't enough in the general case. Have you forgotten 2 others ?

**EDIT** : So the question has been updated. Now there are more constraints, and the problem has one unique solution.
The resolution with this instance is quite straightforward, but I'll do it step by step.
You have 8 variables that you want to know the value :

- **a** : Strawberry only ;
- **b** : Vanilla only ;
- **c** : Chocolate only ;
- **d** : Strawberry and vanilla but not chocolate ;
- **e** : Strawberry and chocolate but not vanilla ;
- **f** : Vanilla and chocolate but not strawberry ;
- **g** : All three ;
- **h** : None.

You already know that $b=120$ and $g = 30$.
Constraint 2 states that $100$ students like both strawberry and vanilla. But that doesn't forbid them to like chocolate. So we have $d+g = 100$ so $d=70$.In the same way, constraint 3 gives us $a+d = 130$ so $a=60$. Constraint 5 says that $a+b+c = 300$ so $c = 120$ ; constraint 6 that $b+d+f+g=270$ so $f = 50$ and constraint 1 that $a+d+e+g = 250$ so $e=90$.
Finally, $h=600-a-b-c-d-e-f-g = 60$.

So your answers are $h$ ; $600-h$ ; $d+e+f+g$ and $c+e+f+g$. So $60$ ; $540$ ; $240$ and $390$.

**Nota bene** : So I said earlier that this kind of problem can't be solved if the number of constraints isn't equal to the number of variables (which is $2^{\text{number of possbilities}}$), *in the general case*.

There are trivial edge cases, for example if two constraints contradict themselves($a = 10$ and $a = 20$), we know that the problem is unfeasible. If some constraints are repeating themselves ($a+b = 20$ ; $b+c = 30$ ; $a+c = 40$ ; $a+b+c = 45$), we will need additional constraints.

But there are funny cases where the number of constraints is inferior to the number of variables, but the problem still has one unique solution. This happens because the way the problem is stated, there as hidden constraints : *all variables must be $>0$*. A trivial example is "There are $100$ students who are asked if they like $A$ and $B$. $100$ said they like $A$ but not $B$." 4 variables and only 1 constraint, but we still have all the information we need.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: there is more than one answer? Make a Venn diagram. Let the compartments be denoted as follows: Only strawberry, vanilla, chocolate = a, f, e, respectively. Strawberry and Vanilla, Vanilla and Chocolate, Strawberry and Chocolate (but not all three) be b, g, d, respectively. Let all three be c.

We are given $f = 120$. Furthermore, $$a+b+c+d = 250: (1)$$ $$b+c = 100: (2)$$ $$ a+b=130: (3)$$ $$ a+e=180 : (4)$$  $$ b+c+g=150:(5).$$ $$a+b+c+d+g+e = 480 : (6)$$

Edit 3: OP gave the final key to the puzzle, that $c = 30$. Thus, $b = 70, a = 60, e = 120, d = 90$.

Comment: recall from the question that students can choose none of the options

Comment: Is that so? That complicates things then... will edit post

Comment: But how many people didn't like any flavors?

Comment: We have that $a = 60, b = 70, c = 30, d = 90, e = 120, f = 120, g = 50$, and everyone combined is $600$ people, so the number of people who didn't like any flavors if $600 - 60 - 70 - 30 - 90 - 120 - 120 - 50 = 60$ people.